# Syntax error near unexpected token - bash

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a simple `bash` script. It just puts out a few lines based on some conditions being satisfied. I am getting stuck on an `if-else` condition and cannot seem to figure a way out.

Here is the code:

```
if [ ( "${MODE}" == "top10gainers" ) || ( "${MODE}" == "top10losers" ) ]; then
  echo "Top Gainers"
elif [ "${MODE}" == "solo" ]; then
     echo "Going solo"
fi
```

The error I get is:

```
syntax error near unexpected token `"${MODE}"'
`if [ ( "${MODE}" == "top10gainers" ) || ( "${MODE}" == "top10losers" ) ]; then'
```

I have googled and tried to search forums (including SO) but have not come across a solution. I have also tried out different brackets in the `OR` condition, but they have not worked either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[ "${MODE}" == "top10gainers" ] || [ "${MODE}" == "top10losers" ]
```

or

```
[ "${MODE}" == "top10gainers" -o "${MODE}" == "top10losers" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

Parentheses execute their contents in a subshell, that's not what you want, and strings are compared with a single `=`.

```
if [ "${MODE}" = "top10gainers" ] || [ "${MODE}" = "top10losers" ]; then
  echo "Top Gainers"
elif [ "${MODE}" = "solo" ]; then
     echo "Going solo"
fi
```

Note that if you want to compare numbers in the future, use `-eq` instead of `=`.

Edit: Testing, I found `==` works too, but there's no mention of them in the man page; it might be an extension in the bash built-in version.  I'd stick to `=` if you want to be at all portable.

Comment: the `=` is needed for strict POSIX compliance, but the `==` would also do. Thanks for the reply!!

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you are explicitly using bash (that is, starting with `#!/bin/bash` instead of `#!/bin/sh`) is to use bash's builtin `[[` command, like so:

```
if [[ ${MODE} == top10gainers || ${MODE} == top10loser ]]; then
    echo "Top Gainers"
elif [[ ${MODE} == solo ]]; then
    echo "Going solo"
fi
```

Note that `[[` doesn't require quoting around variables that may contain spaces, unlike `[` or `test`.